# Have two secondary action elements in a list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have created a list in react which has the following structure:

- Avatar
- Text
- Edit icon
- Delete icon

I have created the structure fine until the delete icon. How can I add this? Currently, it is overlapping the edit icon as both are `ListItemSecondaryAction` but I can't find on the documentation how to add an additional object and what it should be called? https://material-ui.com/components/lists/

**Current implementation:**

```
<List>
    <ListItemAvatar>
        <Avatar src="image" />
    </ListItemAvatar>
    <ListItemText primary="name" />
    <ListItemSecondaryAction>
        <IconButton>
            <EditIcon />
        </IconButton>
    </ListItemSecondaryAction>
    <ListItemSecondaryAction>
        <IconButton>
            <DeleteIcon />
        </IconButton>
    </ListItemSecondaryAction>
</List>
```

[image]

Comment: create a stackblitz of this so that we can play around and come up with an answer

Comment: can you just, make only one ListItemSecondaryAction and both edit and delete inside of it, like"<ListItemSecondaryAction><IconButton> <EditIcon /></IconButton><IconButton> <DeleteIcon/></IconButton></ListItemSecondaryAction>"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is almost sufficient to just put both actions in one `ListItemSecondaryAction` (as indicated by comments and another answer). The only issue is that if you have long content it will overlap the first icon.

Here are the styles for the secondary action from [ListItem](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.10.2/packages/material-ui/src/ListItem/ListItem.js#L77):

```
  /* Styles applied to the `component` element if `children` includes `ListItemSecondaryAction`. */
  secondaryAction: {
    // Add some space to avoid collision as `ListItemSecondaryAction`
    // is absolutely positioned.
    paddingRight: 48,
  },
```

The `paddingRight: 48` will not be sufficient for two icons. You can customize this as follows:

```
const ListItemWithWiderSecondaryAction = withStyles({
  secondaryAction: {
    paddingRight: 96
  }
})(ListItem);
```

Here is a full working v4 example (v5 example further down) that shows the first two list items without this customization (so overlap occurs) and the second two with the fix:

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles, withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import List from "@material-ui/core/List";
import ListItem from "@material-ui/core/ListItem";
import ListItemIcon from "@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon";
import ListItemSecondaryAction from "@material-ui/core/ListItemSecondaryAction";
import ListItemText from "@material-ui/core/ListItemText";
import Checkbox from "@material-ui/core/Checkbox";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import CommentIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Comment";
import DeleteIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Delete";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    width: "100%",
    maxWidth: 360,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper
  }
}));

const ListItemWithWiderSecondaryAction = withStyles({
  secondaryAction: {
    paddingRight: 96
  }
})(ListItem);

export default function CheckboxList() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState([0]);

  const handleToggle = value => () => {
    const currentIndex = checked.indexOf(value);
    const newChecked = [...checked];

    if (currentIndex === -1) {
      newChecked.push(value);
    } else {
      newChecked.splice(currentIndex, 1);
    }

    setChecked(newChecked);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <List className={classes.root}>
        {[0, 1].map(value => {
          const labelId = `checkbox-list-label-${value}`;

          return (
            <ListItem
              key={value}
              role={undefined}
              dense
              button
              onClick={handleToggle(value)}
            >
              <ListItemIcon>
                <Checkbox
                  edge="start"
                  checked={checked.indexOf(value) !== -1}
                  tabIndex={-1}
                  disableRipple
                  inputProps={{ "aria-labelledby": labelId }}
                />
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText
                id={labelId}
                primary={`Line item ${value +
                  1} with some more text to make it longer`}
              />
              <ListItemSecondaryAction>
                <IconButton aria-label="comments">
                  <CommentIcon />
                </IconButton>
                <IconButton edge="end" aria-label="delete">
                  <DeleteIcon />
                </IconButton>
              </ListItemSecondaryAction>
            </ListItem>
          );
        })}
      </List>
      <List className={classes.root}>
        {[2, 3].map(value => {
          const labelId = `checkbox-list-label-${value}`;

          return (
            <ListItemWithWiderSecondaryAction
              key={value}
              role={undefined}
              dense
              button
              onClick={handleToggle(value)}
            >
              <ListItemIcon>
                <Checkbox
                  edge="start"
                  checked={checked.indexOf(value) !== -1}
                  tabIndex={-1}
                  disableRipple
                  inputProps={{ "aria-labelledby": labelId }}
                />
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText
                id={labelId}
                primary={`Line item ${value +
                  1} with some more text to make it longer`}
              />
              <ListItemSecondaryAction>
                <IconButton aria-label="comments">
                  <CommentIcon />
                </IconButton>
                <IconButton edge="end" aria-label="delete">
                  <DeleteIcon />
                </IconButton>
              </ListItemSecondaryAction>
            </ListItemWithWiderSecondaryAction>
          );
        })}
      </List>
    </>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Wider secondary action]

Below is an equivalent v5 example. The changes compared to the v4 version are:

- Uses `styled` instead of `withStyles` and `makeStyles`
- Uses `ListItemButton` instead of the deprecated `ListItem` `button` prop
- Add `disablePadding` prop to the `ListItem` elements. This is needed when leveraging `ListItemButton` in order to keep the styling equivalent to the v4 example
- Package names updated from `@material-ui/core` and `@material-ui/icons` to  `@mui/material` and `@mui/icons-material`

```
import * as React from "react";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";
import List from "@mui/material/List";
import ListItem from "@mui/material/ListItem";
import ListItemIcon from "@mui/material/ListItemIcon";
import ListItemText from "@mui/material/ListItemText";
import ListItemButton from "@mui/material/ListItemButton";
import ListItemSecondaryAction from "@mui/material/ListItemSecondaryAction";
import Checkbox from "@mui/material/Checkbox";
import IconButton from "@mui/material/IconButton";
import CommentIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Comment";
import DeleteIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Delete";

const StyledList = styled(List)(({ theme }) => ({
  width: "100%",
  maxWidth: 360,
  backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper
}));

const ListItemWithWiderSecondaryAction = styled(ListItem)(({ theme }) => ({
  "&.MuiListItem-secondaryAction": {
    paddingRight: 96
  }
}));

export default function CheckboxList() {
  const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState([0]);

  const handleToggle = (value) => () => {
    const currentIndex = checked.indexOf(value);
    const newChecked = [...checked];

    if (currentIndex === -1) {
      newChecked.push(value);
    } else {
      newChecked.splice(currentIndex, 1);
    }

    setChecked(newChecked);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <StyledList>
        {[0, 1].map((value) => {
          const labelId = `checkbox-list-label-${value}`;

          return (
            <ListItem key={value} disablePadding>
              <ListItemButton
                role={undefined}
                dense
                onClick={handleToggle(value)}
              >
                <ListItemIcon>
                  <Checkbox
                    edge="start"
                    checked={checked.indexOf(value) !== -1}
                    tabIndex={-1}
                    disableRipple
                    inputProps={{ "aria-labelledby": labelId }}
                  />
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText
                  id={labelId}
                  primary={`Line item ${
                    value + 1
                  } with some more text to make it longer`}
                />
              </ListItemButton>
              <ListItemSecondaryAction>
                <IconButton aria-label="comments">
                  <CommentIcon />
                </IconButton>
                <IconButton edge="end" aria-label="delete">
                  <DeleteIcon />
                </IconButton>
              </ListItemSecondaryAction>
            </ListItem>
          );
        })}
      </StyledList>
      <StyledList>
        {[2, 3].map((value) => {
          const labelId = `checkbox-list-label-${value}`;

          return (
            <ListItemWithWiderSecondaryAction key={value} disablePadding>
              <ListItemButton
                role={undefined}
                dense
                onClick={handleToggle(value)}
              >
                <ListItemIcon>
                  <Checkbox
                    edge="start"
                    checked={checked.indexOf(value) !== -1}
                    tabIndex={-1}
                    disableRipple
                    inputProps={{ "aria-labelledby": labelId }}
                  />
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText
                  id={labelId}
                  primary={`Line item ${
                    value + 1
                  } with some more text to make it longer`}
                />
              </ListItemButton>
              <ListItemSecondaryAction>
                <IconButton aria-label="comments">
                  <CommentIcon />
                </IconButton>
                <IconButton edge="end" aria-label="delete">
                  <DeleteIcon />
                </IconButton>
              </ListItemSecondaryAction>
            </ListItemWithWiderSecondaryAction>
          );
        })}
      </StyledList>
    </>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit wider secondary action]

Comment: I want the one action button on right and one on left end. I can change it's position by `style={{right : "auto", left: "11%"}}`. So, I need to have two separate `ListItemSecondaryAction` components. Now, the problem is, on the click of last secondary action button, will not trigger the `listitem onClick` event thats fine. but the last but one `ListItemSecondaryAction` button on click is triggering  `listitem onClick` event. which is causing error i.e it's open the accordion in my case. how to avoid that

Comment: more details here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71202550/how-to-have-two-secondary-actions-in-react-material-one-on-left-corner-and-one

Comment: Could you please add a TypeScript example for this? I wasn't able to get the example provided to compile in TypeScript. Specifically, it was complaining about 'withStyles' part.

Comment: @CharlesH Are you using v4 or v5 of MUI?

Comment: @RyanCogswell, I’m using v5. Thank you!

Comment: @CharlesH I've added a v5 example that uses `styled` instead of `withStyles` (which is deprecated in v5).

Comment: @RyanCogswell Thanks so much for the v5 addition to your post, it solved my problem.

Answer (score 4):

I removed `ListItemSecondaryAction` entirely and replaced it with `ListItemIcon`, so now the code looks something like this:

```
<ListItem>
    <ListItemAvatar>
        <Avatar src="image" />
    </ListItemAvatar>
    <ListItemText primary="name" />
    <ListItemIcon>
        <IconButton>
            <EditIcon />
        </IconButton>
    </ListItemIcon>
    <ListItemIcon>
        <IconButton>
            <DeleteIcon />
        </IconButton>
    </ListItemIcon>
</ListItem>
```