# How to have two Secondary Actions in react material, One on left corner and one on right without affecting the behaviour of secondary action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I need to show two secondary action one on left end(eye icon) and one on right end(delete icon) of the list item. The position I can adjust by overriding css elements `right & left`.

[image]

The problem is Secondary action `delete` is also triggering the `ListItem's onClick` event. because in code the order is like below, first delete, and at last eye component is written.

code sandbox link https://codesandbox.io/s/problem-video-forked-oh65hb?file=/demo.js:2568-3179

```
                <ListItemSecondaryAction style={{ right: "11%", left: "auto" }}>
                  <IconButton
                    onClick={(event) => {}}
                    edge="end"
                    aria-label="delete"
                  >
                    <DeleteIcon />
                  </IconButton>
                </ListItemSecondaryAction>

                <ListItemSecondaryAction style={{ right: "auto", left: "11%" }}>
                  <IconButton edge="end" aria-label="delete">
                    {<VisibilityIcon id="entity" />}
                  </IconButton>
                </ListItemSecondaryAction>
```

So, clicking on eye will not trigger any extra onclick event but clicking on delete will do so. coz delete is not written as last element.

How to avoid this, How to have two secondary action buttons on left and right end of the list item without affecting behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Secondary actions are dealt with differently in v5, so this answer only applies to v4 (and the sandbox in the question is using v4).

When MUI renders a ListItem with a secondary action, it renders it with the following structure (I've added "data-desc" attributes to encompass my comments about the structure):

```
<li data-desc="This is the Container component">
   <div data-desc="This is the element that behaves like a button and has the corresponding hover effect.">
      {listItemChildrenExceptForSecondaryAction}
   </div>
   {secondaryAction}
</li>
```

The way that MUI gets the secondary action to avoid triggering the hover and click events of the main button portion of the list item is by [plucking it out of the list of children](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/v4.12.3/packages/material-ui/src/ListItem/ListItem.js#L186) and rendering it outside of the button. The positioning puts it visually within the button, but it is outside of the button with regard to the DOM structure.

MUI only does this for a secondary action that is the last child of the `ListItem`, so if you want another secondary action, you need to get it rendered outside of the button through a different mechanism. One way to achieve this is to override the "Container" component and pass the additional action to it as a prop so that it can render it outside of the button (which will be part of the `children` of the container).

Here's a modified version of your sandbox that uses this approach:

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import List from "@material-ui/core/List";
import ListItem from "@material-ui/core/ListItem";
import ListItemIcon from "@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon";
import ListItemText from "@material-ui/core/ListItemText";
import Divider from "@material-ui/core/Divider";
import Collapse from "@material-ui/core/Collapse";
import ExpandLess from "@material-ui/icons/ExpandLess";
import ExpandMore from "@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import DeleteIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Delete";
import Visibility from "@material-ui/icons/Visibility";
import VisibilityOff from "@material-ui/icons/VisibilityOff";
import ListItemSecondaryAction from "@material-ui/core/ListItemSecondaryAction";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    width: "100%",
    maxWidth: 360
  }
}));

const VisibilityIcon = ({ id }) => {
  const [entVisibility, setEntVisibility] = React.useState(true);
  return entVisibility ? (
    <Visibility
      onClick={() => {
        setEntVisibility(false);
      }}
    />
  ) : (
    <VisibilityOff
      onClick={() => {
        setEntVisibility(true);
      }}
    />
  );
};

const CustomContainerComponent = React.forwardRef(
  function CustomContainerComponent(
    { children, extraSecondaryAction, ...other },
    ref
  ) {
    return (
      <li ref={ref} {...other}>
        {children}
        {extraSecondaryAction}
      </li>
    );
  }
);
export default function SelectedListItem() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = React.useState(null);
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const items = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    items.push(`Entity Name ${i}`);
  }

  const subItems = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    subItems.push(`subitem ${i}`);
  }

  const handleListItemClick = (event, index) => {
    setSelectedIndex(index);
    setOpen(!open);
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <List component="nav" aria-label="main mailbox folders">
        {items.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <React.Fragment key={index}>
              <ListItem
                ContainerComponent={CustomContainerComponent}
                disableRipple
                button
                ContainerProps={{
                  extraSecondaryAction: (
                    <ListItemSecondaryAction
                      style={{ right: "11%", left: "auto" }}
                    >
                      <IconButton
                        onClick={(event) => {}}
                        edge="end"
                        aria-label="delete"
                      >
                        <DeleteIcon />
                      </IconButton>
                    </ListItemSecondaryAction>
                  )
                }}
                selected={selectedIndex === index}
                onClick={(event) => handleListItemClick(event, index)}
              >
                <ListItemIcon style={{ flex: "1" }}>
                  <IconButton edge="start" aria-label="delete">
                    {open && selectedIndex === index ? (
                      <ExpandLess />
                    ) : (
                      <ExpandMore />
                    )}
                  </IconButton>
                </ListItemIcon>

                <ListItemText primary={item} style={{ flex: "3" }} />

                <ListItemSecondaryAction style={{ right: "auto", left: "11%" }}>
                  <IconButton edge="end" aria-label="delete">
                    {<VisibilityIcon id="entity" />}
                  </IconButton>
                </ListItemSecondaryAction>
              </ListItem>

              <Collapse
                in={open && selectedIndex === index}
                timeout="auto"
                unmountOnExit
              >
                <List component="div" disablePadding>
                  <ListItem button>
                    <ListItemText primary="subItem" style={{ flex: "4" }} />
                  </ListItem>
                </List>
                <Divider />
              </Collapse>
            </React.Fragment>
          );
        })}
      </List>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit two secondary actions]

Comment: This is the answer I'm looking for thank you. one doubt from where you took this variable names `{ children, extraSecondaryAction, ...other },`. can u add some explanation only for this overriding function.

Comment: `extraSecondaryAction` could have any name. It just needs to be the same name in the custom container component and when it is passed via the `ContainerProps` ListItem prop.

Comment: Is there any difference in performance between the `e.stopPropagation();` in below answer and with overriding method in your answer? I need to know what's the proper way.

Comment: Using your `stopPropagation` approach addresses the click behavior, but doesn’t address the hover effect — if you hover over the two secondary actions in your approach, you’ll see that one still causes the entire list item to be highlighted rather than just the action.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it finally with `e.stopPropagation()`

```
<IconButton
                    onClick={(e) => {
                      e.stopPropagation();
                    }}
                    edge="end"
                    aria-label="delete"
                  >
                    {<VisibilityIcon id="entity" />}
                  </IconButton>
```